# Using BufferedReader to take input in java

Tags: java

I have been using the Scanner object to take in input until now and would like to learn how the BufferedReader works. I have tried it and it seems to be working only for Strings. can someone show me how to use it with ints and doubles?and how do you ask for two String inputs on the same line? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think of `BufferedReader` and `Scanner` as being at different levels of abstraction, rather than interchangeable parts that "do the same thing." I think this is the fundamental issue that you're hung up on.

`BufferedReader` is in some sense "simpler" than `Scanner`. `BufferedReader` just reads `String`s.

`Scanner` is much more robust than `BufferedReader`. It has APIs that make it easy for extracting objects of various types.

I could imagine `Scanner` being written using `BufferedReader` as an underlying building block. Whereas using `Scanner` to write `BufferedReader` would be like killing an ant with a sledgehammer.

Comment: +1 for `killing an ant with a sledgehammer`. Which is really not fun for either the ant or the hammer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, bufferedreader will take only Strings. you need to convert them into int or double as required using Integer.parseInt(value) or Double.parseDouble(value)

Comment: okay and how do you ask for two String inputs on the same line?

Comment: with Scanner you could use the scan.next() function but with bufferedreader? Thanks

Comment: Lines are distinguished based on "\n" which is enter.

Answer (score 2):

BufferedReader basically takes a input stream as an argument.

You have to use in-built methods to parse string into `ints and doubles`.

Like :

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input1.txt"))
String line = br.readLine();
//more logic here

 int number = Integer.parseInt(brstring);
 double number = Double.parseDouble(brstring);
```

Comment: could you tell me how to ask for two String inputs on the same line? thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can use it with String, int & double.

```
package com.example;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Test {
    public static  void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String name = bufferedReader.readLine();

        int number = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());                                              

        double d = Double.parseDouble(bufferedReader.readLine());

        System.out.println(name);

        System.out.println(number);

        System.out.println(d);

    }
}
```